# Facebook sdk 4.0 : LoginButton state is not working correctly

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a few questions which I need to find solution for.I am using LoginButton but it is not working right.I have listed questions priority wise i.e first question has highest priority.I want to use Facebook Sdk 4.0 but I am facing following problems.

Q1. **Facebook button State issue**: In the case of normal flow of facebook login ,it is working fine but if I close app forcefully immediately after giving the app  permissions (i.e if i am setting the permissions using this statement:

```
 mLoginWithFaceBook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile",        "email"));
```

)
using the OK button of facebook sdk ,after that I am not able to control the state of login button.

I have following **issue:**

-In the above use case no callback method gets called .Actually, I want to successfully logout from facebook after fetching the facebook information of user but in this case since no callback is getting called so I am not able to do that. So when user opens the app again  the button state is not maintained correctly.In the normal scenario, I am doing logout in callbacks.

**How to solve the above issue?**

Q2. **Facebook button text issue**:I want the text of FacebookButton to remain same ,so I do added the the following in the string file for all three cases

```
 <string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Log in with Facebook</string>


<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Log in with Facebook</string>


<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with Facebook</string>
```

but in default case "com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long" text is looking right (i.e no width and height issues) but for other  cases I see only **Log in** (i.e for com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button and com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long **button's text**).

If I do match_parent for height and width of Loginbutton(here LoginButton's parent is taking the whole width of the screen) then button is showing whole text for above not working  cases .

***Actually I want to do this :***

**1**.Button text should be **Login With Facebook** but Button's width should be wrap_content

**2**.whatever use case may be, when the user clicks on **Login With Facebook** ,sdk must ask for permissions(i.e through OK and CANCEL button) . It need not to show 
any alert like you need to logout this user first which my **Login With Facebook** is showing.

I write the  following code snippet to achieve this,but it don't help:

**added LoginButton to LinearLayout** which is taking width of whole screen(this I don't want to do, it should be wrap content but not working for me as mentioned above)

**added three strings in string file**

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Log in with Facebook</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Log in with Facebook</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with Facebook</string>
```

**And use the following code:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
            revokePermissions();//this is my method for revoking the permissions which i was given previously.
            logout();
        }
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    }
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mLoginWithFaceBook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        // If using in a fragment
        mLoginWithFaceBook.setFragment(this);

        // Callback registration
        mLoginWithFaceBook.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FaceBookListener());
        mLoginWithFaceBook.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private class FaceBookListener implements FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile profile) {

                    if (profile != null) {
                       //doing some work here
                }
            };
            mProfileTracker.startTracking();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            revokePermissions();
           LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
           revokePermissions();
           LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();


        }
    }
```

**Please provide any help if you faced the same problem.Any kind of help will be 
appreciated.**